# Finding series solution up to defined order

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I need to find the series solution up to O($x^6$) of the following diff eq

$y''+\sin(x)y'+\cos(x)y=0 $

I would like to confirm: Does this mean find all terms up to and including those with $x^6$ or excluding them? i.e only up to terms with $x^5$.

If someone could also provide a contextual definition of the order of this equation that would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is asking for the terms of the Taylor series of the solution up to $x^5$ included; the rest of the series is $O(x^6)$. As for the second question, it is a second order equation because the highest derivative in the equation is $y''$: a second derivative.